# LWC: Input field not updating when removing characters

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an issue, where an onchange event is firing and working correct, but the field is not updating when removing characters.

```
<lightning-input-field
            field-name="Phone"
            onchange={handlePhoneChange}
            data-phone="phone"
          ></lightning-input-field>
```

This fires the following method:

```
handlePhoneChange(e) {
        const countryCode = `+${this.countryCodes[e.target.getAttribute("data-phone")]}`;
        const targetField = e.target;
        const codeLength = countryCode.length;
        let phoneNumber = targetField.value;

        if (!phoneNumber.includes(countryCode)) {
            for (let i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
                if (phoneNumber[i] !== countryCode[i]) {
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.slice(0, i) + countryCode[i] + phoneNumber.slice(i);
                }
            }
        }
        targetField.value = phoneNumber;
    }
```

I added a console log to check the value and it's correct. Moreover, I realized that when adding characters again, it works. Example:
Country is Switzerland so the country code is +41. When I remove the 1, the input field will show +4, but now I press for example 7, the input field will show +417.

I can't figure out why the update is not working the moment I remove a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decomposing the available input listeners with a simple component:

```html
 <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone"
                                   onkeyup={handleup}
                                   onkeydown={handledown}
                                   onkeypress={handlepress}
                                   onchange={handlechange}
                                   data-phone="phone"> </lightning-input-field>
```

```js
handleup(e) {
  console.log('keyup');
}

handledown(e) {
  console.log('keydown');
}

handlepress(e) {
  console.log('keypress');
}

handlechange(e) {
  console.log('onchange');
}
```

Typing into the input, we can notice that events are triggered in this order:

- keydown
- keypress
- onchange
- keyup

It seems that `onchange` for `lightning-input-field` is some custom implementation of the change event from salesforce since `onchange` event in regular html/js behaves differently:

[doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

> onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed

It's hard to say why exactly the `event.target.value`, even if overwritten in every event - still can be modified. My guess is lwc has a proxy layer that decouples UI value and the actual value of the input.
Anyhow, there are two variants I can think of that can specifically fix your problem:

- switch to the onkeyup event
- prevent any delete operations with `event.preventDefault()` if the user tries to remove the country code

I'll show the example for the first variant:

```html
<lightning-input-field field-name="Phone"
                       onkeyup={handlePhoneChange}
                       data-phone="phone"> </lightning-input-field>
```

```js
countryCodes = {phone: "41", business: "41", mobile: "41"};
handlePhoneChange(e) {
    const countryCode = `+${this.countryCodes[e.target.getAttribute("data-phone")]}`;
    const targetField = e.target;
    const codeLength = countryCode.length;
    let phoneNumber = targetField.value;

    if (!phoneNumber.includes(countryCode)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
            if (phoneNumber[i] !== countryCode[i]) {
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.slice(0, i) + countryCode[i] + phoneNumber.slice(i);
            }
        }
    }
    targetField.value = phoneNumber;
}
```

With this setup, the last event to manipulate your input is the `keyup` event. This results in this behavior:

[image]

Comment: Hi Oleksii, thank you for the reply. The country codes get returned from an apex class. I have a dropdown list, and once a country is selected there, the country code is saved in an object looking like this: {phone: "41", business: "41", mobile: "41"). The data-phone is used to determine which number, as I have three separate phone fields and want to use the same method. In your short video I actually see the same issue I have. Once you removed the 1, it did not refresh the input field. Only when you typed the 2, the 1 also came back.

Comment: for clarification, the replacing itself is working fine. I added a console log after the assignment to phoneNumber, and it is showing the correct number with the fixed country code. The issue is only that the UI is not reflecting this.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof. Ah, sorry with more context now I understand what you mean. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @KrzysztofChabowski I've updated the answer. Now it should more accurately answer your question.

Comment: Thank that was it! I was assuming, that ischanged runs as the last one.